# Is there kubectl filter command to get the PVC - it's volume - mounted in pod -hosted in node fields?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, command-line, kubectl

I am trying to get pvc and it's volume and in which pod it is mounted and the node it is hosted.

There are separate commands are there like below

To get PVC and it's volume

```
kubectl get pvc <pvcname>
```

then from PVC i am getting where it is mounted

```
kubectl describe pvc <pvcname> | grep Mounted
```

Then getting the pod , i am find in which node the pod is hosted

```
 kubectl get pod <pod name> -o wide
```

As often i need to check this and having lot of PVC created by PVC config ,running one by one is complex task. May be a script can be written. Is there any other way using kubectl filter i can get these in single command?

Currently i am doing like this and finding node names where the pvc is mounted.

```
pvc_list=$(kubectl get pvc | awk '{print $1}')
pod_list=$(kubectl describe pvc $pvc_list | grep Mounted | awk '{print $NF}')
kubectl get pod $pod_list -o wide
```

But I need to get like this

```
PVC_name volume Pod_Name Node_Name
PvcTest   voltest  pod1   node1
```

Answer (score 2):

A PVC can be used on any number of pods so this model does not match how Kubernetes works. You could of course write your own script that ignores that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

As of now i have written powershell script using pwsh 7.0 .
For future readers , i record this.

```
$pvcobj = kubectl get pvc --no-headers |  awk '{print $1,$3}'
$pvc_list = foreach($pvc in $pvcobj){

    $pvc_name = $pvc.split(' ')[0]
    $vol_name = $pvc.split(' ')[1]    
    $pod_name = $(kubectl describe pvc $pvc_name | grep Mounted | awk '{print $NF}')
    $node_name = $(kubectl get pod $pod_name --no-headers -o wide | awk '{print $7}' )

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Pvc = $pvc_name
        Volume = $vol_name
        Pod = $pod_name
        Node = $node_name
    }
}
$pvc_list
```

Store it in some ps1 file and run it